# Google Recommendations AI sample rest request

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to build a simple recommendation engine using **Google Recommendations AI** and referring their [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/setting-up). currently I have build a simple curl request and whenever I execute it i get different errors, but all the time error code is 404,i have given sample curl request i have sent

```
    DATA='{
  "id": "1234",
  "category_hierarchies": [ { "categories": [ "athletic wear", "shoes" ]  } ],
  "title": "ABC sneakers",
  "description": "Sneakers for the rest of us",
  "language_code": "en",
  "tags": [ ],
  "product_metadata": {
    "exact_price": {
      "display_price": 99.98,
      "original_price": 111.99 },
    "costs": {
      "manufacturing": 35.99,
      "other": 20
    },
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "canonical_product_uri": "https://www.example.com/products/1234",
    "images": [ ]
   }
}'

curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer access toke is given here" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d "${DATA}" \
  "https://recommendationengine.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/catalogItems:import"
```

Many times i get as string lent is not specified or sometimes blank 404 error message, Any elp would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The url has `[PROJECT_ID]`, are you replacing that with your own PROJECT_ID?

Comment: yes project id and key is replaced with actual values

Comment: From the docs, a JSON file in GCS in snake_case, but an inline request appears to be camelCase. Looks like you may need to switch to camelCase for your fields.

GCS:
- https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#storage

Inline: 
1) https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#inline
2) https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/manage-catalog#single